# No architectures to compile for iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a project to my iPhone 5s, and receive the error

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).

The current build architecture is $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set below setting in your project's Build setting

```
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add arm64 to Valid Architectures of your target in build settings?

Comment: ah ok i added them all on to valid as well.. weird why theres 2 sections, the error is gone but i got a bunch of others for some reason now

Comment: First of all please accept my answer.Then you can post another question with other errors.Thanks.

Comment: i have to wait 10 mins after posting before being allowed to accept

Comment: Ok @rld001.No problem. :)